# How to show result in terms of $\pi$ in Mathcad?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, math-software, mathcad

> Is it possible to display a result in Mathcad as a function of $\pi$?

I'm studying physics and I need to show exact results at the exams. I know I can set Mathcad to give me the result in decimals or in fractions, but none of them are good enough.

**Example: calculating 400/200 $\pi$**

What mathcad can give me: $(400/200) \cdot  \pi  = 6.283$  or $(400/200) \cdot \pi  = 10838702/1725033 $

What I want: $(400/200) \cdot \pi  = 2 \pi$

Comment: Which accuration do you need ? And what kind of function of $\pi$ are we talking about ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow a few guidelines in your question.  In particular, please be more clear in what you mean by "function of pi." Do you mean "multiple of pi"? Also, this does not seem to be a question about mathematics, but rather about Mathcad. Please rewrite your question, if possible, to be about mathematics.

Comment: I will do that :)

Comment: @Rory Daulton: No, it is absolutely [on topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to pose a question about Mathcad. If it is a question about Mathcad it does not make sense to change it in a question about anything else. I think the post is about symbolic calculation in Matchcad.

Comment: @miracle173: Yes, you are right that the page you referenced declares questions about "Software that mathematicians use" are on-topic. Thanks for the correction. I withdraw my close vote.

Comment: Your answer should not have been edited into the question, since it is an actual answer to the question. For now, I posted it as a "community wiki" answer. If you are still around, you can undelete yours and I'll delete my copy. Also, please note this is not a chatty forum; I edited out all emoticons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see results as an expression of something else, then put that at the end of the result (in this case, after 6.283). In that way you can express results in different units or if you want to see it in PIs, then inset a pi symbol (p and alt+g) at the end. If the result is not shown properly, then highlight pi and set it as a constant. In that way it will turn green and the result will be accurate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution (found by the OP): one  can use "CTRL + ." instead of " = " in Mathcad. That gives  the  desired form of result.

Comment: The questions is still open and the answer was not satisfied